# Can't Dispose my tcpClient so i can reuse it again?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient

I am using TcpClient For a simple example of Socket Connection.

when the client connects :

```
clientSocket.Connect("192.168.1.3", 8888);
label1.Text = @"connecting...";
```

The client have to send me some data to the server (an english word), the server will then process that data, and return the result (definition of that word) ! after that the connexion must be stopped ! **(when i say connexion needs to be stop i have no idea what i need to close and what i need to dispose)**

anyway to stop which one of those should i use :

```
clientSocket.Client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
clientSocket.Client.Dispose();
clientSocket.GetStream().Close();
clientSocket.Close();
```

my first problem is that when i try to connect again to the server with the same client (reuse the clientSocket) it gives me this exception, and it marks the clientSocket :

```
Message=Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient'.
Source=System
ObjectName=System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient
```

my sec problem is : to inform the client that the server want him to stop the connexion, it send a string message : "$" ! so each time the client receive a message, it checks if it is "$", if yes ! it start closing... im sure there is a better way to do that, can you please help me, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`Socket.Close()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wahsac9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The Close method closes the remote host connection and releases all managed and unmanaged resources associated with the Socket.

This means that calling `.Dispose()` yourself prior to closing will result in the "Cannot access a disposed object" error since `.Close()` will try to dispose (and close) the already disposed object.

Solution is easy: don't call `.Dispose()` yourself and let `.Close()` handle it.

Comment: Excuse me tried it but the problem is the same ! do i need to provide you more infomations ?

Comment: Yes, you should. What is `clientSocket.Client`? What are all these things that you're closing?

Comment: My Bad, it is working, it seems that all you have to do is : clientSocket.Close();

Comment: But What about my sec problem please, isn't there a way to close the TcpClient by sending like a signal or remotely from the server ?

Comment: I'm just thinking out loud here, but it seems to me that you should just be able to use `while(clientSocket.Connected)`. It will automatically stop once the connection is closed on the other side.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I will never call `Dispose` "after" calling `Close` on an object.
As an API user, I would just be calling `Dispose` and expect the API to do the right things for me.

The using(IDisposable) pattern is there for a reason! When using that, you are not concerned about any managed/unmanaged resource leaks.